# Retrieve data from Database in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I want to retrieve data from database in yii according to increase order of `correct`. But when I am trying to use the following code :

```
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $criteria->condition = '`user_id`= '.$user_id.' AND `quiz_id` ='.$quizid;
        $criteria->order = 'correct DESC';
        $viewquiz = Result::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

then I am getting all the rows from the database that has user_id and quiz_id, but when I am trying to print them into a table then the last row in the database table is displayed in the starting in view and remaining data is displayed in descending order of `correct`

What is wrong with this ?

Comment: Your code seems fine, but I would recommend you parameterize the variables and use `$criteria->addCondition()` instead of directly overwriting the `condition` property, since it may be set previously with some default value.

Answer (score 0):

Got my answer,

Actually the thing I was missing was the structure of the field, I had taken that `varchar`, but for assending or decending, it should be `int`

Comment: Are you saying the field was not ordering because it was a varchar instead of an int type. I don't believe that, as the order by clause works on strings as well as it does on number fields.